# Android Studio 3.0 unknown element <library> found

Tags: android

After I updated Android Studio, one of my projects cannot be built. The error message is:

```
Error:(20) error: unknown element <library> found.
Error:(20) unknown element <library> found.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > Failed to execute aapt
```

My SDK version is 25. I have tried to invalidate cache and add `distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-2-all.zip`, and both of them don't work for me.

Here is my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

annotationProcessor "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:${dbflow_version}"
compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:${dbflow_version}"
compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow:${dbflow_version}"

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'

compile 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:face:1.3.0'
}
```

This is the error log after removing DBFlow:

```
Error:(20) error: unknown element <library> found.
Error:(20) unknown element <library> found.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: This is coming from one of your dependencies. Examine the merged manifest (see the Merged Manifest sub-tab when editing your manifest) and see where it is coming from.

Comment: Why are you adding filetree 2 times?

Answer (score 11):

Add this code in `gradle.properties` in the root project:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

[image]

Comment: What does this do specifically?

Comment: as @udit-kapahi points out, this solution is no longer working

Answer (score 7):

In android studio version 3.1.2 the solution

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

is no longer working.

The root cause of this problem is the Manifest MERGE, which happens when you try to include other dependencies in your project.

To inspect the error

1. Open AndroidManifest.xml
2. On bottom of the window select **Merged Manifest Tab**
3. Browse your manifest file now, and check the portion of manifest being in the slightly red background or lookup for **library** tag.
4. Right click and select **Go To Declaration**. Inspect the file and check which library/depencency it belongs to.
5. Either remove that library or update it from the repo.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

This is a reported issue on [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Vision-Android/issues/25). The issue in the `projectoxford` seems to be fixed already at v.1.0.395

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the annotation processor that you have added this line `annotationProcessor "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:${dbflow_version}"` if you have used any other remove that also

As in studio 3.0 onwards they have inbuilt annotation processor

Comment: I found the reason. It comes from the Microsoft dependency. But is there anyway that I can fix it without removing it?

Comment: I am not sure, I have never worked with that, maybe try reducing your gradle version from 3.0.0 to 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

You need simply to add this to your Android manifest

```
<library tools:node="removeAll" />
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: Where should add this.

Answer (score 0):

It requires to append xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" into manifest, so I wrote:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   <!-- ADD THIS LINE -->
    package="com.microsoft.projectoxford.visionsample" >

    <!-- ... -->

    <library tools:node="removeAll" />
</manifest>
```