# Android Studio error - AAPT: error: unexpected element <library> found in <manifest>

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this error when I run my app: `AAPT: error: unexpected element <library> found in <manifest>`.
I am building a face emotion detection app using Microsoft project oxford emotion 1.0.355. In `AndroidManifest.xml` file I have this

```
<uses-sdk 
     android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30"/>, but when I go on Merged MAnifest tab and click on library in order to go to the declaration, I arrive in jetfied-emotion-1.0.355\AndroidManifest.xml. Here I have 
<uses-sdk 
      android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>.
```

Is this the problem? What should I do?

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.androidemotiondetection">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AndroidEmotionDetection">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your manifest here so we can see

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.androidemotiondetection">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        ....
    </application>

</manifest>`

Comment: My problem is somehow related to this one: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062866/android-studio-3-0-unknown-element-library-found/50596372#50596372?newreg=080e72db2a6f41e4a48cb91bbf79edd5) but when I follow the steps suggested in an answer, I don't really understand how should I either remove that library or update it from the repo

Comment: your manifest is fully wrong here put it in your question with full code